# Do I have to crop images in Photoshop before placing them into InDesign

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, photo-editing

I have to place about 200 images into a Layout in Indesign, most images need to be cropped. Is there any disadvantage if I don't crop the images first in Photoshop? The Layout is for a book design which will be printed offset.

Comment: Hi Sylvia, Welcome to GraphicDesign.StackExchange. We hope you enjoy sharing knowledge and experience.

Comment: The printing method does not affect your preparation of the artwork, per se.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. In fact, there is an advantage by not doing so which is you can reframe in InDesign and have room for playing with them.

But if your images need a "mechanical" crop, for example, all were well taken and framed correctly, but you need a square proportion, you can benefit for some automatization, like a Ps action.

---

In the old days where you could send the base files (Indesign) and you were limited by space, yes, the "norm" was to crop and resize before so you sent smaller files.

But normally these days you send a PDF that automatically crops and resample the images (and the bandwidth is enough where you do not really need to save space)

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to crop in Photoshop, just link them as they are in ID and use the crop in ID. This will not affect print quality at all.

Answer (score 0):

***Always*** size an image to the right number of pixels using Photoshop. While reducing or enlarging using InDesign is possible; doing this will increase the amount of time it takes to output the job. (**Time is money**).

Comment: Especially if you have to do a lot of them to process.

Comment: This seems completely backwards to me. Since illustration sizes and crops are often tweaked as you work on the layout in InDesign in order for everything to match up properly, making pixel-perfect versions of each illustration in Photoshop would be significantly **more** time-intensive than just making the changes directly in InDesign. I would actually say the best advice is the exact opposite of what you give: ***always*** size and crop images directly in the layout for decrease the amount of time spent working on the job. The output time increase pales in comparison.